# Why is this code not entering data into the SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_NAME, firstNumber); // Contact Name
values.put(KEY_PH_NO, strfinal); // Contact Phone
// Inserting Row
dbs.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
```

This code is unable to write the data into the SQLite database. This code is in the onCreate function of the SQLite database, so I haven't called getWritableDatabase() as that gives the following error: "getDatabase called recursively.".

What is going wrong?

EDIT: Here is the LogCat:

```
    03-27 14:38:45.325: D/im invoked(2152): a!!
03-27 14:38:45.325: I/ActivityManager(323): START u0 {cmp=com.example.policeradioscanner/.ListViewA (has extras)} from pid 2152
03-27 14:38:45.336: W/WindowManager(323): Failure taking screenshot for (123x164) to layer 21020
03-27 14:38:45.356: I/Choreographer(2152): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:38:45.546: I/Choreographer(323): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:38:45.926: D/Listvewa main for a==3 invoked(2152): million
03-27 14:38:45.936: D/3(2152): value of a
03-27 14:38:45.936: D/in a==3(2152): twitch
03-27 14:38:45.966: D/above calculations(2152): hitler
03-27 14:38:46.675: D/fcked here8(2152): twitch1
03-27 14:38:47.755: I/Choreographer(323): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:38:48.035: I/Choreographer(323): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:38:49.295: I/Choreographer(323): Skipped 126 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:38:49.705: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 301K, 12% free 3326K/3780K, paused 76ms+103ms, total 509ms
03-27 14:38:50.515: I/Choreographer(323): Skipped 126 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:38:50.985: I/Choreographer(323): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:38:51.315: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 501K, 17% free 3324K/3976K, paused 7ms+15ms, total 204ms
03-27 14:38:51.315: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 52ms
03-27 14:38:51.435: D/dalvikvm(323): GC_CONCURRENT freed 602K, 22% free 5765K/7328K, paused 36ms+73ms, total 471ms
03-27 14:38:51.596: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 382K, 18% free 3284K/3976K, paused 74ms, total 75ms
03-27 14:38:52.005: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 416K, 17% free 3301K/3976K, paused 77ms+15ms, total 280ms
03-27 14:38:52.005: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 127ms
03-27 14:38:52.265: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 390K, 17% free 3304K/3976K, paused 8ms+14ms, total 124ms
03-27 14:38:52.265: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 102ms
03-27 14:38:52.885: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 453K, 17% free 3300K/3976K, paused 12ms+11ms, total 247ms
03-27 14:38:52.885: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 40ms
03-27 14:38:53.636: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 446K, 17% free 3309K/3976K, paused 8ms+31ms, total 173ms
03-27 14:38:53.636: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 125ms
03-27 14:38:53.826: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 394K, 18% free 3281K/3976K, paused 93ms, total 95ms
03-27 14:38:54.366: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 427K, 18% free 3292K/3976K, paused 78ms+31ms, total 296ms
03-27 14:38:54.366: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 73ms
03-27 14:38:55.026: D/ExchangeService(1159): Received deviceId from Email app: null
03-27 14:38:55.026: D/ExchangeService(1159): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
03-27 14:38:55.246: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 404K, 16% free 3343K/3976K, paused 74ms+96ms, total 310ms
03-27 14:38:55.366: W/ActivityManager(323): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
03-27 14:38:55.436: W/ActivityManager(323): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{410490b8 u0 com.example.policeradioscanner/.ListViewA}
03-27 14:38:56.086: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 433K, 17% free 3340K/3984K, paused 73ms+92ms, total 295ms
03-27 14:38:56.436: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 421K, 18% free 3299K/3988K, paused 87ms, total 91ms
03-27 14:38:56.986: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 444K, 17% free 3348K/3988K, paused 78ms+27ms, total 274ms
03-27 14:38:58.066: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 468K, 17% free 3341K/4000K, paused 10ms+66ms, total 395ms
03-27 14:38:59.246: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 451K, 17% free 3339K/4000K, paused 18ms+102ms, total 363ms
03-27 14:39:00.106: D/ExchangeService(1159): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
03-27 14:39:00.126: D/ExchangeService(1159): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
03-27 14:39:00.146: W/ActivityManager(323): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-27 14:39:00.146: D/ExchangeService(1159): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
03-27 14:39:00.176: W/ActivityManager(323): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-27 14:39:00.196: D/ExchangeService(1159): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
03-27 14:39:00.356: I/Choreographer(1404): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:00.416: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 445K, 17% free 3335K/4000K, paused 73ms+77ms, total 565ms
03-27 14:39:00.586: I/Choreographer(1404): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:01.196: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 467K, 17% free 3326K/4000K, paused 17ms+13ms, total 156ms
03-27 14:39:01.206: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 76ms
03-27 14:39:01.576: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 450K, 18% free 3310K/4000K, paused 15ms+17ms, total 120ms
03-27 14:39:01.576: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 107ms
03-27 14:39:01.796: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 18% free 3311K/4000K, paused 12ms+14ms, total 134ms
03-27 14:39:01.796: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 124ms
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cdbca8 that was originally bound here
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cdbca8 that was originally bound here
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-27 14:39:01.896: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-27 14:39:02.036: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 371K, 18% free 3309K/4000K, paused 155ms, total 156ms
03-27 14:39:02.326: I/Choreographer(484): Skipped 1084 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:02.466: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 369K, 17% free 3326K/4000K, paused 17ms+13ms, total 193ms
03-27 14:39:02.466: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 178ms
03-27 14:39:02.996: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 453K, 18% free 3318K/4000K, paused 21ms+30ms, total 170ms
03-27 14:39:03.006: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159): null
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cdbca8 that was originally bound here
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-27 14:39:03.266: E/StrictMode(1159):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-27 14:39:03.366: W/ActivityManager(323): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@41007aa0
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf19e0 that was originally bound here
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf19e0 that was originally bound here
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-27 14:39:03.466: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159): null
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf19e0 that was originally bound here
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-27 14:39:03.646: E/StrictMode(1159):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-27 14:39:03.686: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 430K, 18% free 3313K/4000K, paused 15ms+51ms, total 258ms
03-27 14:39:04.006: W/ActivityManager(323): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@41018628
03-27 14:39:04.596: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 431K, 17% free 3345K/4000K, paused 73ms+95ms, total 300ms
03-27 14:39:05.166: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 483K, 17% free 3323K/4000K, paused 73ms+11ms, total 167ms
03-27 14:39:05.166: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 80ms
03-27 14:39:05.356: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 382K, 18% free 3285K/4000K, paused 86ms, total 87ms
03-27 14:39:05.616: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 412K, 18% free 3302K/4000K, paused 72ms+9ms, total 151ms
03-27 14:39:05.616: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 72ms
03-27 14:39:05.876: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 388K, 17% free 3321K/4000K, paused 77ms+18ms, total 185ms
03-27 14:39:05.876: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 63ms
03-27 14:39:06.126: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 401K, 18% free 3316K/4000K, paused 73ms+10ms, total 143ms
03-27 14:39:06.126: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 65ms
03-27 14:39:06.546: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 474K, 18% free 3307K/4000K, paused 72ms+14ms, total 204ms
03-27 14:39:06.546: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 33ms
03-27 14:39:06.846: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 397K, 18% free 3296K/4000K, paused 76ms+24ms, total 217ms
03-27 14:39:06.846: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 141ms
03-27 14:39:07.296: W/ProcessStats(323): Skipping unknown process pid 2534
03-27 14:39:07.336: W/ProcessStats(323): Skipping unknown process pid 2536
03-27 14:39:07.486: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 434K, 18% free 3304K/4000K, paused 7ms+21ms, total 257ms
03-27 14:39:07.486: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 236ms
03-27 14:39:08.126: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 452K, 18% free 3286K/4000K, paused 7ms+22ms, total 293ms
03-27 14:39:08.126: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 72ms
03-27 14:39:09.407: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 396K, 17% free 3357K/4000K, paused 9ms+103ms, total 395ms
03-27 14:39:10.296: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 492K, 18% free 3311K/4008K, paused 8ms+38ms, total 312ms
03-27 14:39:10.296: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 63ms
03-27 14:39:10.845: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 433K, 18% free 3316K/4008K, paused 77ms+24ms, total 234ms
03-27 14:39:11.345: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 480K, 18% free 3323K/4008K, paused 72ms+9ms, total 156ms
03-27 14:39:11.345: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 72ms
03-27 14:39:11.795: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 471K, 18% free 3318K/4008K, paused 73ms+14ms, total 215ms
03-27 14:39:11.795: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 63ms
03-27 14:39:12.435: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 477K, 18% free 3315K/4008K, paused 72ms+13ms, total 192ms
03-27 14:39:12.435: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 44ms
03-27 14:39:12.985: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 441K, 18% free 3321K/4008K, paused 72ms+30ms, total 232ms
03-27 14:39:13.715: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 432K, 17% free 3339K/4008K, paused 73ms+95ms, total 287ms
03-27 14:39:14.315: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 472K, 18% free 3318K/4008K, paused 77ms+18ms, total 247ms
03-27 14:39:14.315: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 38ms
03-27 14:39:14.886: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 447K, 18% free 3317K/4008K, paused 73ms+29ms, total 236ms
03-27 14:39:15.666: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 472K, 17% free 3328K/4008K, paused 86ms+14ms, total 295ms
03-27 14:39:15.666: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 53ms
03-27 14:39:16.476: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 444K, 17% free 3356K/4008K, paused 72ms+33ms, total 259ms
03-27 14:39:17.518: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 473K, 17% free 3327K/4008K, paused 8ms+69ms, total 350ms
03-27 14:39:17.518: D/dalvikvm(2152): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 183ms
03-27 14:39:19.266: D/dalvikvm(2152): GC_CONCURRENT freed 460K, 17% free 3338K/4008K, paused 8ms+88ms, total 556ms
03-27 14:39:19.626: I/SQLiteConnectionPool(2152): The connection pool for /data/data/com.example.policeradioscanner/databases/feedsmanager.sqlite has been closed but there are still 1 connections in use.  They will be closed as they are released back to the pool.
03-27 14:39:19.626: D/asdf is fcked,ctid is 96(2152): hitler
03-27 14:39:19.656: D/asdf is fcked(2152): hitler
03-27 14:39:19.656: D/asdf is(2152): twitchfinal
03-27 14:39:19.656: D/3(2152):  a!! before 
03-27 14:39:19.656: D/4(2152):  a!! after 
03-27 14:39:19.736: I/Choreographer(2152): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:20.116: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-27 14:39:20.576: I/Choreographer(2152): Skipped 960 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:20.836: I/Choreographer(323): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:20.916: I/Choreographer(323): Skipped 100 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:20.956: I/ActivityManager(323): Displayed com.example.policeradioscanner/.ListViewA: +35s541ms
03-27 14:39:20.966: I/Choreographer(2152): Skipped 233 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:21.276: I/Choreographer(2152): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:21.336: I/Choreographer(2152): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:21.436: I/Choreographer(2152): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:38.186: I/Choreographer(323): Skipped 94 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:38.235: I/Choreographer(323): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:38.295: I/Choreographer(323): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:38.515: I/Choreographer(323): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 14:39:45.749: D/ExchangeService(1159): Received deviceId from Email app: null
03-27 14:39:45.749: D/ExchangeService(1159): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
03-27 14:39:50.816: D/ExchangeService(1159): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
03-27 14:39:50.836: D/ExchangeService(1159): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
03-27 14:39:50.846: D/ExchangeService(1159): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
03-27 14:39:50.866: W/ActivityManager(323): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-27 14:39:50.866: D/ExchangeService(1159): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
03-27 14:39:50.886: W/ActivityManager(323): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d31658 that was originally bound here
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d31658 that was originally bound here
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-27 14:39:50.936: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159): null
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d31658 that was originally bound here
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-27 14:39:50.956: E/StrictMode(1159):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-27 14:39:50.976: E/ActivityThread(1159): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce41a0 that was originally bound here
03-27 14:39:50.976: E/ActivityThread(1159): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce41a0 that was originally bound here
03-27 14:39:50.976: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-27 14:39:50.976: E/ActivityThread(1159):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
```

Comment: @jlordo No answer there solves my problem. Also no correct answer has been selected in that question.

Comment: You have to put the green tick next to the best answer. The community can only give up or downvotes. Also, we'll lose interest in helping you, if you don't provide the information we ask for. Since you posted the same code as yesterday, have you tried anything else and followed the advice from my comment on the duplicate question?

Comment: @jlordo Yes i did what you said, used Log.d in the try catch, no error is thrown, and the logcat had tens of thousands of lines, posting it there wouldn't be efficient..

Comment: Clear the logcat, run your app and save the logcat. This should bring down the number of lines, and we can take a look at it. Also, not sure if this will help: in your `CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE` String, have a semicolon at the end (as last character of the String and let me know if it helps or not).

Comment: Also, why do you have this line `db = this.getWritableDatabase();` **after** this line `db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);`? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: @jlordo Adding the semicolon didn't help.. I'm posting the logcat as an edit.

Comment: that's an absolutely duplicate of your own question from only a few hours ago. I voted to close it and I hope 3 more people vote to close it too.

Comment: post your database relevant code.

Comment: @HoanNguyen What exactly??

Comment: Your database code for creation table, minus all the one about selects, insert etc.. I ran an example in my database class and I have no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove `db.close();` from the code. For whatever reason, it was preventing anything from being written into the database. Removed it and data enters perfectly.